# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when using XPATH with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

Though I have added a reference to the `System.Xml.Xpath` from Silverlight 5, I still get this error when trying to get a link with a certain class from a HTML document:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code:

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(New Net.WebClient().DownloadString(sourceUrl))

For Each row As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='base-link']")
    Console.Write(row.Name)
Next
```

If I only do `SelectNodes("//a")`, then I don't get any error. Looks, like there's a problem when using `@class` but I don't understand why

Comment: You didn't told us on which line the error is. Did you check of SelectNodes actualy returns something?

Comment: @the_lotus, the error occurs at `SelectNodes`. It does not return anything

Comment: You only need to use the Silverlight 5 System.Xml.Xpath if you are writing a Silverlight 5 program, otherwise it will work with the usual System.Xml assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception occurs because there are no nodes selected with your XPath query.

You can guard against it with something like:

```
Option Infer On
' ... '
Dim myLinks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='base-link']")
If myLinks IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each row In myLinks
        Console.WriteLine(row.Name)
    Next
End If
```

I suggest that you inspect the HTML you are loading to find out what the class name is. It could be that the class name is generated by, say, JavaScript, in which case you would have to load the page into a browser control and wait for it finish processing, then get the rendered HTML and parse that.